# How to get original position of a pixel after a remap in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

assume that I have a set of remap such as this: (assume that images are set and the code is working)

```
for(int i=0; i<NumberOfImages; i++)
{
    remap( inputImage, outImages[i], m_mapX[i], m_mapY[i], CV_INTER_NN );
}
```

Now I want to find the position of pixel (X,Y) on input image on outputImages (assuming that remap is in a way that any pixel on input image is mapped to only one output image)

The simplest way is to do a search on all m_mapX and m_mapY and look for requested pixel, but it is very time consuming. is there any better way to do so?

Assume that I have a big list of points that I need to convert, so probably creating a reverse map is better, but how to create a reverse map?

Comment: If the remap is 1:1 as you said, then just remap using the inverse of the mapping function used to create the original mapping.

Comment: @RogerRowland: Can be more specific? Any sample code?

Comment: You didn't show how you created the mapping. Can you give the code that populates `m_mapX` and `m_mapY`?

Comment: I build a KD-tree for all the points in the map -- if you need to repeat the search many times this works well. Then I used Inverse Distance Weighting so interpolate. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703210/inverting-a-real-valued-index-grid/46009462#46009462

Comment: Could you solve the problem of an inverse remapping in the end?

Comment: did you try [`cv::invert`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#double%20invert(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20flags))?

Comment: @slawekwin how to use it in a remap?

Comment: @mans I'm not sure, but I would try to invert both map mats and call `remap` again

Answer (score 0):

For remapped images, OpenCV (version 4.7 and later) provides a more straightforward approach using the function `[cv::initInverseRectificationMap][1]`. This function is useful when you have the camera matrix (`K`), the distortion coefficients, and the rectification (`R`) and projection (`P`) matrices, typically obtained from camera calibration or stereo rectification. You can use these parameters to compute the inverse rectification map, which will allow you to find the original position of a pixel in the undistorted image after it has been remapped.

This function generates two maps, `invMapX` and `invMapY`, that can be used with `cv::remap` to perform the inverse rectification. The map type `CV_16SC2` is a predefined format used in OpenCV that stores two 16-bit signed integers for each pixel. When using this type, each pixel in `invMapX` and `invMapY` works like a fixed index that points to its corresponding location in the original image.

Here is the corrected code:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

// Assuming these variables are already initialized with valid data:
// k - Camera matrix
// DistCoeff - Distortion coefficients
// R - Rotation matrix (rectification)
// P - Projection matrix
// Ncols, Nrows - Size of the image

cv::Mat invMapX, invMapY;
cv::initInverseRectificationMap(k, DistCoeff, R, P, cv::Size(Ncols, Nrows), CV_16SC2, invMapX, invMapY);

// Now, to find the original position of a pixel from a remapped image, you can do the following:
cv::Vec2s pixel = invMapX.at<cv::Vec2s>(row_from_RemappedImage, col_from_RemappedImage);

// pixel[0] is the x-coordinate, and pixel[1] is the y-coordinate in the original (undistorted) image.
```

You ensure that the matrices `k, DistCoeff, R,` and `P` are correctly initialized with the results from your camera calibration.