# Image warping by a displacement field sampled on a regular grid

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, transform, interpolation

Let's say I have an image *I*(*x,y*) and a vector field ***w***(*x,y*), both sampled on the same regular grid. My goal is to warp the image according to the vector field and create output image *J*(*u,v*). This is done by mapping points (*x,y*) in *I* to points (*u,v*) in *J*. The problem is I don't know what is the easiest way implement this. I have read online that there are basically two main approaches to these kinds of problems.

Forward mapping: simply add the displacement vector to every coordinate (*x,y*) of image *I*. The problem here is that this way I would get non-integer coordinate points (*u',v'*) on a non-regular grid in *J*, because ***w***(*x,y*) is not necessarily integer-valued and varies from pixel-to-pixel. My question is: how can I interpolate this image to integer coordinates? For example, if I would like to calculate the pixel value of *J*(*12,25*), how do I know which sample points to use for the interpolation if the samples are not on a regular grid?

Backward mapping: find out which non-integer coordinates (*x',y'*) in *I* correspond to integer coordinates (*u,v*) in *J* by applying the inverse of the transformation to coordinates (*u,v*). The values corresponding to the non-integer coordinates (*x',y'*) in *I* can then be interpolated easily. My question is: can I apply this to my problem somehow? Can I somehow invert my displacement field? How would I find the inverse of this displacement field that maps integer values from *J* to non-integer values in *I* ?

To clarify, I am not looking for existing implementations of solutions to this problem (I know that there are for example functions in Matlab and OpenCV that can do this). I would only like to understand the theory behind it and start experimenting on my own.

Comment: Have you solved this, David?

Comment: Not really. I still don't know how it is done. I've found some info, e.g. in SimpleITK there is a class called [InverseDisplacementFieldImageFilter](https://itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1InverseDisplacementFieldImageFilter.html). In the description you can find a spline based technique. However, I don't know whether classes like DisplacementFieldTransform or WarpImageFilter in SimpleITK use this method when they warp images using displacement fields.

Comment: If you are still looking for a solution and comments on this, I had to address the same problem lately and submitted my solution to a similar question there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65566295/1560876

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem with bilinear interpolation is how I should find the points I can use for interpolation. E.g.: with forward mapping I want to calculate J(12,25). Maybe I need to interpolate from J(11.5,24.10),J(15.6,21),J(10.6,25.1),J(12.9,26) because these would be the closest neighbours in J in this (made up) example. How do I find out these are the closest points from a list of coordinates? Is there a fast way to do this (maybe sorting+search)? Is there possibly a better way to approach this whole problem or is this the correct approach?