# How to fix error when inversing image maps in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to inverse a set of maps using this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65566295/17004689). I used two of his methods so there is more detail as to how they work in his answer. I also left some comments out to shorten the code.

I have my own camera matrix and distortion coeff's that I use to create an x and y map with `cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap()`, but when I pass them to `invert_maps()` I get an out-of-bounds error shown below.

None of this (except the bottom part) is my code and its pretty advanced stuff so I have no clue how to debug it. And I dont have enough credit to comment on the orignal answer. Anyone got a solution?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv2
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import glob

def bilinear_inverse(p, vertices, numiter=4):

    p = np.asarray(p)
    v = np.asarray(vertices)
    sh = p.shape[1:]
    if v.ndim == 2:
        v = np.expand_dims(v, axis=tuple(range(2, 2 + len(sh))))

    # Start in the center
    s = .5 * np.ones((2,) + sh)
    s0, s1 = s
    for k in range(numiter):
        # Residual
        r = v[0] * (1 - s0) * (1 - s1) + v[1] * s0 * (1 - s1) + v[2] * s0 * s1 + v[3] * (1 - s0) * s1 - p

        # Jacobian
        J11 = -v[0, 0] * (1 - s1) + v[1, 0] * (1 - s1) + v[2, 0] * s1 - v[3, 0] * s1
        J21 = -v[0, 1] * (1 - s1) + v[1, 1] * (1 - s1) + v[2, 1] * s1 - v[3, 1] * s1
        J12 = -v[0, 0] * (1 - s0) - v[1, 0] * s0 + v[2, 0] * s0 + v[3, 0] * (1 - s0)
        J22 = -v[0, 1] * (1 - s0) - v[1, 1] * s0 + v[2, 1] * s0 + v[3, 1] * (1 - s0)

        inv_detJ = 1. / (J11 * J22 - J12 * J21)

        s0 -= inv_detJ * (J22 * r[0] - J12 * r[1])
        s1 -= inv_detJ * (-J21 * r[0] + J11 * r[1])

    return s


def invert_map(xmap, ymap, diagnostics=False):
    """
    Generate the inverse of deformation map defined by (xmap, ymap) using inverse bilinear interpolation.
    """

    # Generate quadrilaterals from mapped grid points.
    quads = np.array([[ymap[:-1, :-1], xmap[:-1, :-1]],
                      [ymap[1:, :-1], xmap[1:, :-1]],
                      [ymap[1:, 1:], xmap[1:, 1:]],
                      [ymap[:-1, 1:], xmap[:-1, 1:]]])

    # Range of indices possibly within each quadrilateral
    x0 = np.floor(quads[:, 1, ...].min(axis=0)).astype(int)
    x1 = np.ceil(quads[:, 1, ...].max(axis=0)).astype(int)
    y0 = np.floor(quads[:, 0, ...].min(axis=0)).astype(int)
    y1 = np.ceil(quads[:, 0, ...].max(axis=0)).astype(int)

    # Quad indices
    i0, j0 = np.indices(x0.shape)

    # Offset of destination map
    x0_offset = x0.min()
    y0_offset = y0.min()

    # Index range in x and y (per quad)
    xN = x1 - x0 + 1
    yN = y1 - y0 + 1

    # Shape of destination array
    sh_dest = (1 + x1.max() - x0_offset, 1 + y1.max() - y0_offset)

    # Coordinates of destination array
    yy_dest, xx_dest = np.indices(sh_dest)

    xmap1 = np.zeros(sh_dest)
    ymap1 = np.zeros(sh_dest)
    TN = np.zeros(sh_dest, dtype=int)

    # Smallish number to avoid missing point lying on edges
    epsilon = .01

    # Loop through indices possibly within quads
    for ix in range(xN.max()):
        for iy in range(yN.max()):
            # Work only with quads whose bounding box contain indices
            valid = (xN > ix) * (yN > iy)

            # Local points to check
            p = np.array([y0[valid] + ix, x0[valid] + iy])

            # Map the position of the point in the quad
            s = bilinear_inverse(p, quads[:, :, valid])

            # s out of unit square means p out of quad
            # Keep some epsilon around to avoid missing edges
            in_quad = np.all((s > -epsilon) * (s < (1 + epsilon)), axis=0)

            # Add found indices
            ii = p[0, in_quad] - y0_offset
            jj = p[1, in_quad] - x0_offset

            ymap1[ii, jj] += i0[valid][in_quad] + s[0][in_quad]
            xmap1[ii, jj] += j0[valid][in_quad] + s[1][in_quad]

            # Increment count
            TN[ii, jj] += 1

    ymap1 /= TN + (TN == 0)
    xmap1 /= TN + (TN == 0)

    if diagnostics:
        diag = {'x_offset': x0_offset,
                'y_offset': y0_offset,
                'mask': TN > 0}
        return xmap1, ymap1, diag
    else:
        return xmap1, ymap1


# cam matrix and dist coeff's that I brought

cam_matrix = np.array([ [1223.07784,  0, 926.80065],
                        [ 0, 1231.71291, 546.10496],
                        [ 0,  0,  1]], dtype='float32')

distortion_profile = np.array([-0.32077, 0.15041, 0.001004, 0.00028, -0.04252], dtype='float32')

# get current maps
mapx, mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cam_matrix, distortion, None, cam_matrix, (1920, 1080), 5)

# invert the maps
mapx_invert, mapy_invert = invert_map(mapx, mapy)

# apply mapping to image
inversed = cv2.remap(img, mapx_invert, mapy_invert ,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

cv2.imwrite('inversed.png', inversed)
```

Error:

```
File "c:\Users\...\redist_image2.py", line 121, in invert_map
    ymap1[ii, jj] += i0[valid][in_quad] + s[0][in_quad]
IndexError: index 1382 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1020
```

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: What if you change this axis 0 to axis 1?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz regarding the answer below it, that method only takes the combined x and y map. How do you take the separate x and y maps that are returned from `initUndistortRectifyMap()` and convert them into a x-y combined map?

Comment: pass `m1type=cv.CV_32FC2`, or use convertMaps