# How to convert individual x y maps to 2-channel matrix map in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to do forward mapping with OpenCV, but `remap()` only allows inverse mapping so I need to inverse the map(s) before using them. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68706787/19210678) is the inverse map method I want to use and it only takes in a single 2 channel map.

In the [convert maps](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20convertMaps(InputArray%20map1,%20InputArray%20map2,%20OutputArray%20dstmap1,%20OutputArray%20dstmap2,%20int%20dstmap1type,%20bool%20nninterpolation)) docs it says that you can convert one 2 channel (x,y) map into individual x and y maps. It also says that you can do "Reverse conversion". Does this mean you can convert from x and y maps to a single (x,y) map shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import cv2 as cv

(xymap, _) = cv.convertMaps(map1=xmap, map2=ymap, dstmap1type=cv.CV_32FC2)
```

Documentation isn't terribly obvious. The bullet list only contains the interesting cases (for fixed point math). Your case is just rearranging the values without touching them, which is not listed, but supported. You **can** use `dstmap1type=cv.CV_32FC2`.

Or simply use numpy:

```py
xymap = np.dstack([xmap, ymap])
```

You are working with v2.x documentation... don't. [Use current docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga9156732fa8f01be9ebd1a194f2728b7f). You are very surely *not* using OpenCV v2.x.

Comment: could you modify the inverse map method I linked so that it can take just a 1d map instead of xy?

Comment: but you can simply use a combined x-y-map? why would you need that code modified? if you wanted to modify that code, where are you stuck?

Comment: @ChristophRackwits Nevermind your right I dont need it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I read the docs again. you're absolutely right, they don't actually list your use case, even though the given list suggests totality. it is implemented though.