# Why Imagemagick Composite Displace leaving behind edges, not displacing properly

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, disparity-mapping

I have an image and have a gray mask, I am trying to use fast composite displace to move image but after image is moved it is leaving behind edges:

```
magick flower.jpg flower_depth.png -virtual-pixel Gray -compose Displace -define compose:args=-30x0 -composite flower_result.jpg
```

Any help would be appreciated,  I want to use this fast processing approach... tried very hard even chatgpt is not able to come up with any good solution :D

[image: Main Image]
[image: Gray mask image]
[image: After displace result]

Comment: Can you show the output of `identify -version` please?

Comment: because the depth channel is imprecise. look. it does not align precisely in those places. how did you generate that?

Comment: @MarkSetchell it is: Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-16 Q16 x64 2021-11-21

Comment: It is just a feature of the displace. It has to do with the shape of the image and mask and the brightness of the mask at any pixel. If you do not want a shift, set the mask to 50% gray.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem in Gimp...

And when I look at your image, the displace map exactly overlays the source image, and you are using a negative displacement, two hints that you have fallen victim to a very common misconception.

#### The misconception

Displace maps would describe what happens to the source pixels; in other words, the map would tell how to move the matching source pixel. This is wrong, and there are at least two problems with this assumed behavior:

- this is ambiguous, what do you do when several source pixels are projected to the same result pixel?
- what happens to pixels that are not the destination of a source pixel?

#### The reality (*)

The map tells where the corresponding result pixel comes from (which is unambiguous, and every pixel in the result has a source...).

A corollary is that the displace map shape is usually different from the source, you cannot deduce it simply from the source.

#### Your problem

If you look at your map up close:

- The background is >127, so positive but your displacement is negative so pixels in the result are pixel to the left of this in the source
- The ellipse is <127, so negative but your displacement is negative so pixels in the result are pixel to the right of this in the source

So in:
[image]

- In the green area, result pixels are copied fro the tip of the green arrow so you get a copy shifted left of the ellipse
- in the blue area, result pixels are copied from the tip of the blue arrow, so are a copy of the background.
- In the red area, result pixels are copied from the tip of the red arrow so you get a shifted right copy of the ellipse.

So you get ellipse-background-ellipse and you see a gap.

If you want to stretch that part, the background and the ellipse should be moved by roughly the same amount, so the displace map cannot have a hard edge, in should on the contrary be uniform (or have a very slow gradient)(this is an application of the corollary above).

#### However....

Going back to the initial problem, what are you trying to achieve, because I don't think the displace map is a solution...  (ask a new question if so).

(*) At least in Gimp, but I can reasonably assume that it works like other software

Comment: makes total sense, to me at least. there are [iterative ways to invert such maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703210/inverting-a-real-valued-index-grid/68706787#68706787). this would allow one to define the forward map, then invert it, then apply it. takes just a few cheap iterations. that may be a path towards a solution. I can't predict how discontinuities will behave through this inversion.