Invert undistortion done in OpenCV (recover the original image)
I have an application where I use a 3D model developed through photogrammetry to map between a 2D -> 3D space and back (3D -> 2D). The photogrammetry software (reality capture) "undistorts" the input images before making the model. I need to be able to develop a mapping between the reality capture (undistorted) images and the original images.
Reality capture gives:

The focal length (f=fx=fy) in 35 mm film format
The deviation of the optical center (dcx, dcy) in 35 mm film format
The distortion coefficients used (k1, k2, p1, p2, k3, k4,...)

The distortion models of interest are:

Division (single radial parameter)
Brown3/4 (3/4 radial parameters)

I am able to use the code below to recreate the undistorted images from reality capture with only a small amount of error from the original images, but I'm unable to recreate the original images from the undistorted ones. I've read that there is a way  to do this using OpenCV with the cv2.remap method, but I can't find a way to do it. Any feedback is appreciated.
NOTE: I'm using python, but if someone has an answer using cpp I'm happy with that as well.
CODE:
import cv2
import os

import numpy as np

SENSOR_WIDTH = 36.
SENSOR_HEIGHT = 24.

img_dir = [pth_to_imgs]

for img_pth in img_dir: 
    img = cv2.imread(img_pth)
    h, w = img.shape[0:2]


    # Calculate the camera intrinsics in the correct frame
    f_35, dcx, dcy, k1, k2, k3, k4, p1, p2 = 25, 7.e-004, -1.e002, 0.1, -0.18, 0.15, 0., 0., 0.
    # Calculate the optical center from the deviations
    cx = (w / SENSOR_WIDTH) * (SENSOR_WIDTH / 2 + dcx)
    cy = (h / SENSOR_HEIGHT) * (SENSOR_HEIGHT / 2 + dcy)

    f = f_35 * w / 36

    # Defining the OpenCV variables
    cameraMatrix = np.array(
        [[f, 0., cx],
         [0., f, cy],
         [0., 0., 1.]]
    )

    distCoeffs = np.array(
        [k1, k2, p1, p2, k3]
    )

    # Calculating the undistortion and rectification maps
    map1, map2 = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(
        cameraMatrix=cameraMatrix, 
        distCoeffs=distCoeffs, 
        R=np.eye(3),
        newCameraMatrix=cameraMatrix,
        size=(w, h),
        m1type=cv2.CV_32FC1
    )

    undistImg = cv2.remap(
        src=img,
        map1=map1,
        map2=map2,
        interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR
    )
    
    sv_pth = pth_to_sv_dir

    # cv2.namedWindow('Downloaded Image', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    # cv2.imshow('Downloaded Image', undistImg)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(sv_pth, f'{os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(img_pth)[0])}_OpenCV.JPG'), undistImg)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I've tried using the single parameter division model, negating the distortion coefficient to re-distort the image (recover the original) and it works decently, but it's not perfect, especially in the corners. I'd like a more accurate solution and one that allows me to use a higher-order model (Brown3/4).

It would help to have a distorted and undistorted image to see what you are doing and to use with your code.

get the undistortion map, invert it, use it. inversion of such maps is an iterative process. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22120, with one question on SO being https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703210/inverting-a-real-valued-index-grid/68706787#68706787

This question is similar to: What are the inaccuracies of this 'inverse map' function in OpenCV?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ChristophRackwitz, you're correct, the def invert_map(F) did what I was looking for with blistering time implications. Thank you for pointing me in this direction!
